# Ionic 2 fail to load resource err_connction_reset when request api url over mobile data

Tags: api, angular, ionic-framework

Ionic 2 app failed to load the resource.

I get err_connction_reset when I send a request to an API over mobile data. Some mobiles work and both work when the mobile request is sent using wifi.
Do I need to configure anything in my mobiles to avoid this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem by reinstall internet settings by re-downloading it.